# Join two SQL tables using ID where ID is text

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables in local SQL database. There is no unique ID field unfortunately and the only matching field is `SNAME`. Is there any SQL Query solution that can be used to join two tables into one.

Here is an example of target I am trying to achieve:

Table `LFI` in database:

```
NRO   SNAME  NAMEA   NAMEB   IADDRESS  POSTA   POSTN   POSTADR   COMPANYN   COUNTRY   BID
123   Fiat   Punto   500     J5        K4      O3      P4        O2         JT        S1
133   Opel   Meriva  FTG     J5        K4      O3      P4        O2         JO        T3
153   MB     E200    C25     JN        KI      OP      PY        OR         JD        Y5
183   BMW    E64     SE0     JR        KE      OT      PG        OL         J8        U9 
103   Audi   S6      700     JP        KU      OU      PN        OH         J6        I11
```

Table `LSE` in database:

```
NRO   SNAME  NAMEA   NAMEB   IADDRESS  POSTA   POSTN   POSTADR   COMPANYN   COUNTRY   BID
423   Fiat   Punto   500     J5        K4      O3      P4        O2         JT        S1
463   BMW    E64     SE0     JR        KE      OT      PG        OL         J8        U9
```

Merged output should look like this:

```
NRO  NRO1   SNAME  NAMEA   NAMEB   IADDRESS  POSTA   POSTN   POSTADR   COMPANYN   COUNTRY   BID
123  423    Fiat   Punto   500     J5        K4      O3      P4        O2         JT        S1
133         Opel   Meriva  FTG     J5        K4      O3      P4        O2         JO        T3
153         MB     E200    C25     JN        KI      OP      PY        OR         JD        Y5
183  463    BMW    E64     SE0     JR        KE      OT      PG        OL         J8        U9
103         Audi   S6      700     JP        KU      OU      PN        OH         J6        I11
```

SQL QUERY task:

Find duplicates in `SNAME`. Leave only one of them, assign a number from Table `LFI` to `NRO` from Table `LSE` to `NRO1`. Table `LFI` numbers should be in `NRO`, Table `LSE` numbers should be in `NRO1`.

I guess I need to create new table with additional column, but how to pass two tables to new one with criteria mentioned above?:

```
CREATE TABLE LMERGED (
NRO int,
NRO1 int,
SNAME text,
NAMEA text,
NAMEB text,
IADDRESS text,
POSTA text,
POSTN text,
POSTADR text,
COMPANYN text,
COUNTRY text,
BID text,
);
```

I have also tried to use JOIN, but text field can't be used as "ID" with JOIN operation:

```
SELECT *
FROM LFI
LEFT JOIN LSE 
ON LFI.SNAME = LSE.SNAME;
```

Comment: *the only matching field is SNAME.* - looks to me like a lot more fields than just SNAME are a match?!

Comment: Create a surrogate primary key and join on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SNAME look pretty small:

```
SELECT *
FROM LFI
LEFT JOIN LSE 
ON CAST(LFI.SNAME AS VARCHAR(20)) = CAST(LSE.SNAME AS VARCHAR(20));
```